# How to turn integers into Fibonacci coding efficiently?

Tags: algorithm, math

Fibonacci sequence is obtained by starting with 0 and 1 and then adding the two last numbers to get the next one.

[image]

All positive integers can be represented as a sum of a set of Fibonacci numbers without repetition. For example: 13 can be the sum of the sets {13}, {5,8} or {2,3,8}. But, as we have seen, some numbers have more than one set whose sum is the number. If we add the constraint that the sets cannot have two consecutive Fibonacci numbers, than we have a unique representation for each number.

We will use a binary sequence (just zeros and ones) to do that. For example, 17 = 1 + 3 + 13. Then, 17 = 100101. See figure 2 for a detailed explanation.

[image]

I want to turn some integers into this representation, but the integers may be very big. How to I do this efficiently.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_coding suggests that a greedy approach does work.

Comment: What do you mean by very big? Do they fit into 64 bits?

Comment: Less than 100 Fibonacci fit in 64 bit. So if your integers are restricted to 64 bit, simply hardcode a table of all the fib numbers you need. See here a list or compute them once yourself. http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibtable.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I want to tell you that I really liked this question, I didn't know that All positive integers can be represented as a sum of a set of Fibonacci numbers without repetition, I saw the prove by induction and it was awesome. 
To respond to your question I think that we have to figure how the presentation is created. I think that the easy way to find this is that from the number we found the closest minor fibonacci item. 
For example if we want to present 40: 
We have Fib(9)=34 and Fib(10)=55 so the first element in the presentation is Fib(9) 
since 40 - Fib(9) = 6 and (Fib(5) =5 and Fib(6) =8) the next element is Fib(5). 
So we have 40 = Fib(9) + Fib(5)+ Fib(2) 
Allow me to write this in C#

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> fibPresentation = new List<int>();
            int numberToPresent = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            while (numberToPresent > 0)
            {
                int k =1;
                while (CalculateFib(k) <= numberToPresent)
                {
                    k++;
                }
                numberToPresent = numberToPresent - CalculateFib(k-1);
                fibPresentation.Add(k-1);
            }
        }
        static int CalculateFib(int n)
        {
            if (n == 1)
                return 1;

            int a = 0;
            int b = 1;
            // In N steps compute Fibonacci sequence iteratively.
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                int temp = a;
                a = b;
                b = temp + b;
            }
            return a;
        }
    }
```

Your result will be in fibPresentation

Answer (score 3):

The problem itself is simple. You always pick the largest fibonacci number less than the remainder. You can ignore the the constraint with the consecutive numbers (since if you need both, the next one is the sum of both so you should have picked that one instead of the initial two).

So the problem remains how to quickly find the largest fibonacci number less than some number X.
There's a known trick that starting with the matrix (call it M)

```
1 1
1 0
```

You can compute fibbonacci number by matrix multiplications(the xth number is M^x). More details here: https://www.nayuki.io/page/fast-fibonacci-algorithms . The end result is that you can compute the number you're look in O(logN) matrix multiplications.

You'll need large number computations (multiplications and additions) if they don't fit into existing types.
Also store the matrices corresponding to powers of two you compute the first time, since you'll need them again for the results.

Overall this should be O((logN)^2 * large_number_multiplications/additions)).

Answer (score 2):

This encoding is more accurately called the "Zeckendorf representation": see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_coding

A greedy approach works (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeckendorf%27s_theorem) and here's some Python code that converts a number to this representation. It uses the first 100 Fibonacci numbers and works correctly for all inputs up to 927372692193078999175 (and incorrectly for any larger inputs).

```
fibs = [0, 1]
for _ in xrange(100):
    fibs.append(fibs[-2] + fibs[-1])

def zeck(n):
    i = len(fibs) - 1
    r = 0
    while n:
        if fibs[i] <= n:
            r |= 1 << (i - 2)
            n -= fibs[i]
        i -= 1
    return r

print bin(zeck(17))
```

The output is:

```
0b100101
```

Answer (score 1):

As the greedy approach seems to work, it suffices to be able to invert the relation `N=Fn`.

By the Binet formula, `Fn=[φ^n/√5]`, where the brackets denote the nearest integer. Then with `n=floor(lnφ(√5N))` you are very close to the solution.

```
17 => n = floor(7.5599...) => F7 = 13
4 => n = floor(4.5531) => F4 = 3
1 => n = floor(1.6722) => F1 = 1
```

(I do not exclude that some `n` values can be off by one.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is an efficient enough for you, but you could simply use Backtracking to find a(the) valid representation.

I would try to start the backtracking steps by taking the biggest possible fib number and only switch to smaller ones if the **consecutive** or the **only once** constraint is violated.